# My car is a May 2017 Tata Bolt

Tags: transmission

At 20,000 Kls my car had a massive gear box failure when taking off in first gear. because no spares were available it took ten weeks to repair.

Three month later, three days before the 30,000 Kls service, with 30,260
kls on the clock the clutch plate failed, I had been experiencing loss of power going up hills, but never experiencing a clutch failure before, I was not aware that it could have been the clutch.

could the gear box failure contributed to the clutch failure.

Answer (score 1):

The clutch failing is, almost certainly, a separate issue.

Clutches fail prematurely for basically two reasons:

One: material failure due to a defect

Two: poor driving technique ie slipping the clutch or sidestepping the clutch.

Never had a driver admit to either, but seen the results...

Once taken apart, the cause may be identified, but at 30k plus they may just say wear & tear... Especially as you say it was loosing power, which probably means it was slipping for a period of time.